# Como limitar exibição de registros de acordo com parâmetros

Tags: php, mysql

Estou com um problema e a solução que estou tentando aplicar não me parece ser a mais indicada, preciso mostrar alguns resultados de determinados produtos limitando essa exibição, tenho o seguinte `sql` que gera os `grupos` de produtos:

```
SELECT
 agrGrupoPrecoCialAgr.Descricao,
 agrAgroProduto.Nome,
 agrPrecoComercialAgr.DataValidadeInicial,
 agrPrecoComercialAgr.HoraValidadeInicial,
 agrPrecoComercialAgr.DataValidadeFinal,
 agrPrecoComercialAgr.HoraValidadeFinal,
 agrPrecoComercialAgr.PrecoFinal,
 agrPrecoComercialAgr.IdAgroProduto
FROM
 agrGrupoPrecoCialAgr
 INNER JOIN agrPrecoComercialAgr
  ON agrGrupoPrecoCialAgr.IdGrupo = agrPrecoComercialAgr.IdGrupo
 INNER JOIN agrAgroProduto
  ON agrPrecoComercialAgr.IdAgroProduto = agrAgroProduto.IdAgroProduto
WHERE
 agrPrecoComercialAgr.IdUnicoop = 33                                                             
 AND agrGrupoPrecoCialAgr.MostraPainel = 1
 AND agrPrecoComercialAgr.DataValidadeInicial = '$dataCalendario'
 AND agrGrupoPrecoCialAgr.IdGrupo = '$idGrupo'
 AND agrGrupoPrecoCialAgr.Descricao <> 'GOIAS'
 AND agrGrupoPrecoCialAgr.Ativo = 1
ORDER BY
 agrGrupoPrecoCialAgr.Ordem ASC,
 agrPrecoComercialAgr.IdAgroProduto ASC
```

Com esses dados estou montando um `xml`

```
do {    
    // NOME DO PRODUTO          
    $nome  = str_replace("", "", $rstPreco['Nome']);
    $nome  = str_replace("", "", $nome);        
    // PREÇO DO PRODUTO
    $preco = number_format( $rstPreco['PrecoFinal'], $casasDecimais, ',', '.' );
    // IDENTIFICAÇÃO DO PRODUTO
    $IdAgroProduto = $rstPreco['IdAgroProduto'];
    if ($preco == "0,00"){
            $preco = "F.M.";                                
    }
    // MOSTRA PREÇOS APARTIR DAS 13:00 HS.
    // LIMITAR A EXIBIÇÃO NESSE MOMENTO
    if ($hora >= $rstPreco['HoraValidadeInicial'] && $hora \r\n");
            fwrite($fp, "".$IdAgroProduto."\r\n");                         
            fwrite($fp, "$nome\r\n");
            fwrite($fp, "$preco\r\n");                           
            fwrite($fp, "\r\n");                             
    } else {                            
            fwrite($fp, "\r\n");
            fwrite($fp, "".$IdAgroProduto."\r\n");                             
            fwrite($fp, "$nome\r\n");
            fwrite($fp, "N.D\r\n");                          
            fwrite($fp, "\r\n");                         
    }

} while ($rstPreco = mysql_fetch_assoc($conPreco));
```

Da quantidade de registros obtidos não posso exibir todos, por isso estava tentando fazer um `if` com todos os `id´s` que posso mostrar, mas não ficou muito legal, por isso gostaria de sugestões de como resolver isso.

O que tentei fazer foi isso:

```
do {    
// NOME DO PRODUTO          
$nome  = str_replace("<b>", "", $rstPreco['Nome']);
$nome  = str_replace("</b>", "", $nome);        
// PREÇO DO PRODUTO
$preco = number_format( $rstPreco['PrecoFinal'], $casasDecimais, ',', '.' );
// IDENTIFICAÇÃO DO PRODUTO
$IdAgroProduto = $rstPreco['IdAgroProduto'];
    if ($preco == "0,00"){
            $preco = "F.M.";                                
    }
    // MOSTRA PREÇOS APARTIR DAS 13:00 HS.
    if ($hora >= $rstPreco['HoraValidadeInicial'] && $hora <= $rstPreco['HoraValidadeFinal']){
        if($IdAgroProduto == 1 || $IdAgroProduto == 74 || $IdAgroProduto == 70 || $IdAgroProduto == 195 || $IdAgroProduto == 196 || $IdAgroProduto == 197|| $IdAgroProduto == 368 || $IdAgroProduto == 75 || $IdAgroProduto == 429 || $IdAgroProduto == 430) {                                              
            fwrite($fp, "<cotacoes>\r\n");
            fwrite($fp, "<codigo>".$IdAgroProduto."</codigo>\r\n");                         
            fwrite($fp, "<nome>$nome</nome>\r\n");
            fwrite($fp, "<valor>$preco</valor>\r\n");                           
            fwrite($fp, "</cotacoes>\r\n");     
        }               
    } else {                        
            fwrite($fp, "<cotacoes>\r\n");
            fwrite($fp, "<codigo>".$IdAgroProduto."</codigo>\r\n");                             
            fwrite($fp, "<nome>$nome</nome>\r\n");
            fwrite($fp, "<valor>N.D</valor>\r\n");                          
            fwrite($fp, "</cotacoes>\r\n");                             
    }
 }

} while ($rstPreco = mysql_fetch_assoc($conPreco));
```

Comment: qual a condição ou quais condições dos registros que você quer exibir?

Comment: Olá @MarllonNasser, preciso mostrar os produtos listados nesse IF que fiz, mas achei o esquema que fiz pode ser melhorado.

Comment: qual a atribuição de `$hora`?

Comment: vc pode fazer um where  agrPrecoComercialAgr.IdAgroProduto in (select  * from produtosquepode);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aconselho o filto direto pela query. Baseado em sua pergunta, dá a entender que você quer filtrar os registros baseados pela hora, mais especificamente às 13h. Ou seja, tudo que for a partir de 13 horas, você filtra os ids XPTO.

Caso você tenha como consolidar essas ids numa query como:

`select IdAgroProduto from agrPrecoComercialAgr where CONDICAO_PARA_EXIBIR_SOMENTE_O_QUE_VC_QUER`

Utilize essa query:

```
SELECT
 agrGrupoPrecoCialAgr.Descricao,
 agrAgroProduto.Nome,
 agrPrecoComercialAgr.DataValidadeInicial,
 agrPrecoComercialAgr.HoraValidadeInicial,
 agrPrecoComercialAgr.DataValidadeFinal,
 agrPrecoComercialAgr.HoraValidadeFinal,
 agrPrecoComercialAgr.PrecoFinal,
 agrPrecoComercialAgr.IdAgroProduto
FROM
 agrGrupoPrecoCialAgr
 INNER JOIN agrPrecoComercialAgr
  ON agrGrupoPrecoCialAgr.IdGrupo = agrPrecoComercialAgr.IdGrupo
 INNER JOIN agrAgroProduto
  ON agrPrecoComercialAgr.IdAgroProduto = agrAgroProduto.IdAgroProduto
WHERE
 agrPrecoComercialAgr.IdUnicoop = 33                                                             
 AND agrGrupoPrecoCialAgr.MostraPainel = 1
 AND agrPrecoComercialAgr.DataValidadeInicial = '$dataCalendario'
 AND agrGrupoPrecoCialAgr.IdGrupo = '$idGrupo'
 AND agrGrupoPrecoCialAgr.Descricao <> 'GOIAS'
 AND agrGrupoPrecoCialAgr.Ativo = 1
 AND ((HOUR(HoraValidadeInicial) > 13 and agrPrecoComercialAgr.IdAgroProduto in (select IdAgroProduto from agrPrecoComercialAgr where CONDICAO_PARA_EXIBIR_SOMENTE_O_QUE_VC_QUER)) or (HOUR(HoraValidadeInicial) < 13))
ORDER BY
 agrGrupoPrecoCialAgr.Ordem ASC,
 agrPrecoComercialAgr.IdAgroProduto ASC
```

Caso você não tenha... utilize especificando os IDS:

```
SELECT
 agrGrupoPrecoCialAgr.Descricao,
 agrAgroProduto.Nome,
 agrPrecoComercialAgr.DataValidadeInicial,
 agrPrecoComercialAgr.HoraValidadeInicial,
 agrPrecoComercialAgr.DataValidadeFinal,
 agrPrecoComercialAgr.HoraValidadeFinal,
 agrPrecoComercialAgr.PrecoFinal,
 agrPrecoComercialAgr.IdAgroProduto
FROM
 agrGrupoPrecoCialAgr
 INNER JOIN agrPrecoComercialAgr
  ON agrGrupoPrecoCialAgr.IdGrupo = agrPrecoComercialAgr.IdGrupo
 INNER JOIN agrAgroProduto
  ON agrPrecoComercialAgr.IdAgroProduto = agrAgroProduto.IdAgroProduto
WHERE
 agrPrecoComercialAgr.IdUnicoop = 33                                                             
 AND agrGrupoPrecoCialAgr.MostraPainel = 1
 AND agrPrecoComercialAgr.DataValidadeInicial = '$dataCalendario'
 AND agrGrupoPrecoCialAgr.IdGrupo = '$idGrupo'
 AND agrGrupoPrecoCialAgr.Descricao <> 'GOIAS'
 AND agrGrupoPrecoCialAgr.Ativo = 1
 AND ((HOUR(HoraValidadeInicial) > 13 and agrPrecoComercialAgr.IdAgroProduto in (1,74,70,195,196,197,368,75,429,430)) or (HOUR(HoraValidadeInicial) < 13))
ORDER BY
 agrGrupoPrecoCialAgr.Ordem ASC,
 agrPrecoComercialAgr.IdAgroProduto ASC
```

E a montagem do seu XML é somente trazendo o que vem da query... toda a regra que antes você tinha feito na montagem, será feito na query.

```
do {    
// NOME DO PRODUTO          
$nome  = str_replace("<b>", "", $rstPreco['Nome']);
$nome  = str_replace("</b>", "", $nome);        
// PREÇO DO PRODUTO
$preco = number_format( $rstPreco['PrecoFinal'], $casasDecimais, ',', '.' );
// IDENTIFICAÇÃO DO PRODUTO
$IdAgroProduto = $rstPreco['IdAgroProduto'];
    if ($preco == "0,00"){
            $preco = "F.M.";                                
    }                  
    fwrite($fp, "<cotacoes>\r\n");
    fwrite($fp, "<codigo>".$IdAgroProduto."</codigo>\r\n");                             
    fwrite($fp, "<nome>$nome</nome>\r\n");
    fwrite($fp, "<valor>N.D</valor>\r\n");                          
    fwrite($fp, "</cotacoes>\r\n");    
 }

} while ($rstPreco = mysql_fetch_assoc($conPreco));
```

Comment: Olá @Marllon Nasser, fantástico, muito obrigado pelas excelentes sugestões.